# On click at one element toogle class at the another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how can I toggle (add/remove) class from element when clicked on whole another element. Right now I am using

```
$('.caption-trigger').click(function(){
    $('.carousel-caption').toogle;
    console.log("Hide caption");
});
```

So when user click on `.caption-trigger` the class is toggled on this element instead on `.carousel-caption`. Does anyone how to deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.toggleClass()`:

```
$('.caption-trigger').click(function(){
    $('.carousel-caption').toggleClass('your-class');
    console.log("Hide caption");
});
```

this will toggle the class `your-class` on the element `.carousel-caption`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incomplete. Otherwise

```
$('.carousel-caption').toggleClass('someClass', booleanVar);
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

.toggle() is used to shor or hide the elements

```
 $('.caption-trigger').click(function(){
            $('.carousel-caption').toggleClass('classname');
            console.log("Hide caption");
        });
```

You can also use animation to toggle the elemnts by setting duration.

```
$('.caption-trigger').click(function(){
                $('.carousel-caption').toggle("slow", function() {
                console.log("Hide caption");.
                  }););   
            });
```